# copying child object to another child object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have Custom Object A and Custom Object B which is a child of A.

I also have Custom Object C and Custom Object D which is a child of C.

When records are created in Custom Object A and B, I need to copy values from A and B to C and D.  So far I have a trigger to copy the data when records are created in Custom_Object_A to Custom_Object_C, but need help with adding code to this trigger to copy the child object records of Custom_Object_B to Custom_Object_D and make sure they're related to their respective parent record.

```
trigger createCFromA on Custom_Object_A (after insert, after update) {

    Id RecTypeId =  [Select Id from RecordType where name = 'recordtype' and sObjectType = 'Custom_Object_C' limit 1].Id;


    List <Custom_Object_C> cToInsert = new List <Custom_Object_C>();


    for (Custom_Object_A a : Trigger.new){        


        if (a.Status__c == 'New' ) {


        Custom_Object_C c = new Custom_Object_C (); 


        c.Field_1__c = a.Field_1__c;
        c.Field_2__c = a.Field_2__c;
        c.Field_3__c = a.Field_3__c;

        c.RecordTypeId = RecTypeId;


        cToInsert.add(c);

        }

    }


    try {
        insert CToInsert; 
    } 
        catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
        system.debug (e);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, but how exactly is the behavior you observe not conforming to the behavior you expect? Can you please **[edit]** your post to be more detailed?

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson.  I updated my example code as I had it wrong.  So B is a child to A and D is a child to C.  The trigger I have is creating a record in Object C when a record is created in Object A, however I need help in grabbing the child records in Object B (related to A) and insert them in Object D which is related to object C.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That's not what comments are for. It's still not clear what your current code does or does not achieve relative to your objective.

Comment: I've edited my post and added more detail around what the trigger is doing now and what I need it to do.  I hope I've added enough to explain it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using Clone method provided by Salesforce?

Comment: Can that run in a trigger? I need this to be a trigger.